# void-variable jdee plugins emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have an issue with the jdee plugin for emacs.

The function jde-javadoc-generator returns:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable working-message)
```

Here is the part i suspect to be the issue in jde-javadoc-generator:

```
...
(jde-javadoc-status-forms "Updating" "done" 
        (jde-javadoc-dynamic-status)
        (setq doctree (jde-javadoc-tag-doctree tag))
        (if (and (fboundp checker)
                 (not (funcall checker tag doctree)))
            (setq report nil)
          (let ((seas semantic-edits-are-safe))
            (make-local-variable 'semantic-edits-are-safe)
            (unwind-protect
                (progn
                  (setq semantic-edits-are-safe t)
                  (when (or (not doctree)
                            (jde-javadoc-delete-documentation
                             tag noconfirm))
                    (funcall generator tag doctree)
                    (jde-javadoc-indent-documentation tag)))
              (setq semantic-edits-are-safe seas))))
        (jde-javadoc-dynamic-status t))
...
```

here is the called functions:

```
(defmacro jde-javadoc-status-forms (message donestr &rest forms)
  "Wrapper for `working-status-forms'.                                                                                                                                                                               
See `working-status-forms' for details on MESSAGE, DONESTR and FORMS                                                                                                                                                 
arguments.  Does not override an outer `working-status-forms'                                                                                                                                                        
MESSAGE."
  `(working-status-forms (or working-message ,message) ,donestr
     ,@forms))

(defun jde-javadoc-dynamic-status (&rest args)
  "Wrapper for `working-dynamic-status'.                                                                                                                                                                             
Does nothing if not called within the macro `working-status-forms'.                                                                                                                                                  
See `working-dynamic-status' for meaning of ARGS."
  (and working-message
       (apply #'working-dynamic-status args)))
```

You can see more here:
https://github.com/emacsmirror/jdee/blob/master/lisp/jde-javadoc.el

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is defined in another library, perhaps something like `cedet`?  If you Google **"working-message" emacs**, you'll see a couple of references to that variable.